# "Cancelling Out" Differential Forms in Chain Rule

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms, differential, chain-rule

Let's think about$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \times \frac{du}{dx}.$$ Here function $u(x)$ is differentiable at $x=x_0$ and $y(u)$ is differentiable at $u=u_0=u(x_0)$.

I know this is a common question, but trying to learn about differential geometry and about differential forms in particular, I thought about the fundamental reason why we can't cancel out the $du$'s. I want you to check if this is correct.

Say that the tangent vector at $x=x_0$ is $\vec{a} = (a_1, a_2)$, and the tangent vector at $u=u_0$ is $\vec{b} = (b_1, b_2)$. Then the $du$ in the former is $du(\vec{a}) = a_2$, a function of $\vec{a}$, and the $du$ in the latter is $du(\vec{b}) = b_1$, a function of $\vec{b}$.

Unless it is a very special case that $a_2 = b_1$, the $du$'s have different values so we can't "cancel out" them (and I personally consider setting $a_2 = b_1$ a bit meaningless and just harms generality).

Is this logic correct?

Comment: It is important to understand that the thing you want to evaluate is the left hand side of your expression. Usually one can perform the differentiation directly. Good. In some cases the relation between y en x is messy. Then it can be useful to differentiate y with respect to some convenient quantity u. The chain rule says this is okay, but you must multiply the result with the derivative of u to x. The fact that this is true, demonstrates the opposite of what you claim: the two du terms do cancel (loosely speaking of course).

Comment: @M.Wind From the fact that I introduced the concepts of differential forms and tangent vector space you may see that I'm not loosely speaking

Comment: I added the phrase "loosely speaking of course" merely as a disclaimer. If I had not done that, there would be mathematicians on this forum who would gladly suggest that I don't know the difference between differentiation and division.

Comment: No, your logic is incorrect. You assume that the derivative is represented by a tangent vector, a two-dimensional quantity. In fact it is represented by a single number, which corresponds to the ratio of your vector components. In other words, the length of the tangent vector is irrelevant. Hence your two vectors can be scaled anyway you want. So the question whether a2 = b1 is true plays no role in the chain rule.

Comment: In what spaces do $x, u$ and $y$ lie?  What is a function of what and via which mappings? Before you set up your problem in a proper way everything else is essentially meaningless.

Comment: @Max Hmm it's not a concrete problem actually, it's just me trying to understand the concepts precisely and fundamentally :(

Comment: Yes, but "the concepts" are meaningless outside of a precise setup. What's worse, some similar looking things (like "dx") have different meaning depending on the setting. You will have a lot of trouble understanding anything before you commit to a specific situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find the entire premise of the question is a little flawed. You want to regard derivatives as *ratios* of the corresponding differentials, but this is simply not true (or at best a bit circular). It's important to keep in mind that $df/dx$ is just notation, and shouldn't really be regarded as a true ratio of well-defined quantities. Differential forms are concepts based on derivatives, not the other way around.

I would go as far as to say that trying to regard the chain rule as "cancellation" is not just wrong, but entirely senseless. However, it is very suggestive nonsense, so it's perhaps worth exploring why it's doomed to failure.

A slight aside first. The way you regard differential forms is not quite correct. Your functions are one-dimensional (judging from context, since you never specified domain), but you take your differential forms to be functions of two-dimensional vectors. This is not how you define differential forms. In your notation, the correct thing would be $du(a_1) = a_2$.

Just to avoid confusion, let us first formalize the concept of a differential form. In one dimension, the concept of a differential form is little more than notation. We define $df_x:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as the linear map
$$df_x(r) = f'(x)r,$$
for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$. Moreover, this is an $x$-dependent linear map. Due to the fact that a linear map in one-dimension is given by a single real number (a $1\times 1$ matrix, if you will), the concept of a differential form here is completely equivalent to the derivative. You gain nothing in one dimension by working with differential forms, which is why you almost never see it used in single variable calculus. The concept of a differential form is non-trivial in higher dimensions however, because the resulting linear maps are no longer trivial.

Now, we could define ratios of differential forms to see what we get. The first thing that goes immediately wrong is that this ratio will be undefined when the form in the denominator is at a critical point. This is already damning in my opinion, but let's continue regardless. Maybe it will work everywhere the ratio is well-defined. Let's use your set up where we have functions $f$ and $u$. Let me call $g = f\circ u$. This brings us to our second issue, which is the fact that the "$df$" on the left-hand side should really be "$dg$". The chain rule written with unambiguous notation should really be
$$\frac{dg}{dx} = \frac{df}{du}\frac{du}{dx},$$
but of course this is not nearly as memorable. The mnemonic for the chain rule relies on the crucial overloading of notation, where we regard $df/dx$ not as the derivative of $f(x)$ but of $(f\circ u)(x)$. When you try to write everything down carefully and unambiguously, you find immediate issues with the ratio interpretation of derivatives. The notation $df/dx$ is not only somewhat misleading, but ultimately ambiguous. This issue is only compounded in higher dimensions with the introduction of various partial derivatives. There, you have more explicit breakdowns, like the [triple product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Your answer helped a lot. But seeing the expression $\frac{df}{du} \times \frac{du}{dx}$, I came up with another approach. Is it mathematically correct to think of the terms $\frac{df}{du}$ and $\frac{du}{dx}$ separately and think of two separate linear maps? So, for two separate variables $r \in R$ and $s \in R$, considering $df_u(r)=f'(u)\times r$ and $du_x(s)=f'(x)\times s$?

Comment: So, what I mean is, (1) Is it a valid reasoning in this way, (2) or is it simply conceptually wrong, (3) or is it still quite meaningless though not wrong because, as you said, the Leibniz notation is merely a mnemonic and the concept of a differential form comes from the idea of derivative, not the other way around?

Comment: @curious It's not quite clear what you mean. You seem to be asking whether chain rule holds at the level differentials (correct me if I'm wrong). This is indeed true, and in fact, it's probably the more natural form of the chain rule. The act of taking a differential is "natural" in the sense that the differential of a composition is the composition of the differentials. Thus, we have $d(f\circ u)_x = df_u \circ du_x$. If you're interested, I suggest learning some differential geometry, where these concepts are naturally formalized.

Comment: Hmm, the composition of differential doesn't quite come to me. What if $du_x(r)$ is zero? Then $df_u(du_x(r))$ also has to be zero as it is a linear function given by $df_u(du_x(r)) = f'(u) \times du_x(r)$. So basically what makes me feel like it's a contradiction is, in my current understanding we have to separate what becomes the domain of $df$ from what becomes the codomain of $du$.

Comment: @curious I don't understand what you find the contradiction to be. If $du_x(r) = 0$, then we must have $u'(x) = 0$, so we're at a critical point. Since $(f \circ u)'(x) = f'(u(x))u'(x) = 0$, this is also a critical point for $f \circ u$. There is no contradiction here.

Answer (score -1):

If
$$lim_{dx \to 0,dy\to 0}\frac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{lim_{dy \to 0,dt\to 0}\frac{dy}{dt}} {lim_{dx \to 0,dt\to 0}\frac{dx}{dt}}$$

*can be abbreviated* to symbolically denote a ratio of two limits

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{dy}{dt} / \frac{dx}{dt} \tag1$$

then $$ {lim_{dy \to 0,dt\to 0}\frac{dy}{dt}} \cdot {lim_{dx \to 0,dt\to 0}\frac{dt}{dx}}$$

*can as well  be abbreviated* to symbolically denote a product of two limits

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} \tag2 $$

(1) and (2) are obtained by cancellation of differentials . They must be together correct or together wrong.